# Access multilevel key from a JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I have a javascript function which returns the response like this( I am using nodejs and ejs):

```
"index_1": {
    "mappings": {
        "type_1": {
            "properties": {
                "field_1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field_2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "type_2": {
            "properties": {
                "field_1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field_2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field_3": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to access 2nd or third level key from the response. Suppose if I want a list like this:

```
type_1
type_2
```

or

```
field_1
field_2
field_3
```

How can I do that? If I use `callback(Object.keys(response))` then it returns `index_1`. Can anyone point me to right direction?

Comment: Do you need a particular field or type, or would you like to perform something for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple one-liner, I suppose.

```
Object.keys( object );
```

returns only first level keys (that's the reason you get **index_1**).

**Solution 1**

If you know, that response, has alway a structure of:

```
var jsonObject = {
   "index_1" : { 
       "mappings": {
            "type1" : ... ,
            "type2" : ...
       }
};
```

Then you only need to pass:

```
callback(Object.keys(jsonObject.index1.mappings));
```

That way you'll get third level keys.

But if you don't know the structure, or want to access keys of any level, then recursion might be helpful.

```
var jsonObject = {
   "index_1" : {
       "mappings": {
            "type1" : { field1 : {}, field2 : 2} ,
            "type2" : {}
       }
   }
};

// 1..N, and 1 means you want to get **index_1**
function getNthLevelKeys( json, level ) {
      var keys = [];
      var currLvlKeys = Object.keys(json);
      level = level - 1;

      if ( typeof json !== 'object' || json === null) {
          return [];
      }

      if ( level > 0 ) {

           for (var i = 0; i < currLvlKeys.length; i++) {
               keys = keys.concat(getNthLevelKeys( json[ currLvlKeys[i] ] , level ));
            }
      }

      if (level === 0) {
            return currLvlKeys;
      }

      if (level < 0) {
           throw new Error("Cannot access level "+level+" of this object");
      }

      return keys;
}

console.log(getNthLevelKeys( jsonObject , 1));
console.log(getNthLevelKeys( jsonObject , 2));
console.log(getNthLevelKeys( jsonObject , 3));
console.log(getNthLevelKeys( jsonObject , 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the keys of a sub-object, you need to pass this particular sub-object to `Object.keys()`:

```js
var data = {"index_1":{"mappings":{"type_1":{"properties":{"field_1":{"type":"string"},"field_2":{"type":"string"}}},"type_2":{"properties":{"field_1":{"type":"string"},"field_2":{"type":"string"},"field_3":{"type":"string"}}}}}};

console.log(Object.keys(data.index_1.mappings));                   
    // ["type_1", "type_2"]

console.log(Object.keys(data.index_1.mappings.type_2.properties)); 
    // ["field_1", "field_2", "field_3"]
```